# Laravel 5 class not found in remote server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, remote-server

I have laravel 5 in a remote server and I have this error `Class 'App\Libraries\CheckLang' not found`.

In CheckLang `namespace App\Libraries;` 
in routes.php `use App\Libraries\CheckLang;`

In local it works but in the remote server no.

I create a folder myapplication with the folders of laravel and in public_html the files of the folder public.

I have modified index.php
`require __DIR__.'/../ myapplication/bootstrap/autoload.php';`
`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myapplication/bootstrap/app.php';`

Thank you

Comment: did you copy your local working directory or had a fresh installation of laravel on remote server?

Comment: It is a fresh installation

Comment: so you need to add the package and update the autoloaders? are you using composer? also why dont you use git to do the deployment on server? (sorry out of topic but i think it would be easier that way)

Comment: I use composer in local and I go up with FTP in the shared server. With Laravel 4 there were no problem.

Comment: do you have SSH access? even readonly?

Comment: Probably a file case sensitivity issue. Is your local machine Windows? Check that the file is `CheckLang.php` not `Checklang.php`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
composer update
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for Ammadu,
it was a problem of uppercase.